Tkinter after function is freezing the program
I'm trying as a beginner in tkinter to do a simple connect buttons game where you connect Spanish words with their English counterparts.
Code knows when the connection which user makes is wrong and when that happens I want the buttons that were chosen to change the colour for red and make buttons unusable by changing their command for function that is doing nothing. Until now everything is working alright but next I wont these buttons to come back to normal state after 3 sec. I'm trying to use .after to achieve this.
Right now code changes colour only of one button because its still in writing but even though this change is made after few second of freeze of window when nothing works and from what I know this is not how after function should work.
I want to button change the colour and command without freezing; I tried a lot of things like changing place of .after in code putting whole after line directly or by calling it from function, but nothing seems to work the way I want. The issue here is probably me not understanding how the threads and .after works. So sorry for trouble and thanks for help in advance. Here is part of the code I have issue with.
def color_red(whatever_button, whatever_word, func):

    whatever_button.after(6000, whatever_button.config(fg='orange',command=lambda: func(whatever_button, whatever_word)))
def uncorrect():

     no_yellow = True
     unknown_button_f.config(fg='red', command = nothing)
     previous_button.config(fg='red', command = nothing)
     if unknown_button_f in spanish_list:
         print('spanish')
         unknown_button_f.after(3000, lambda: color_red(unknown_button_f, unknown_word_f, button_connect_spanish))
         # previous_button.after(3000, lambda: color_red(previous_button, previous_word, button_connect_english))
     else:
         print('vanish')
         color_red(unknown_button_f, unknown_word_f, button_connect_english)


Same as command with .after you need to provide it a function to call such as using lambda. Your code is immediately calling .config in the color_red function. You've done it correctly in uncorrect

whatever_button.after(6000, whatever_button.config(...) is equivalent to whatever_button.config(...) and then time.sleep(6). You probably want to put the whatever_button.config(...) in a lambda

Thank you very much for that help. You explained it very well and code runs just as i wont right now. Now when i think about it seems logical, thank you again for fast help!
